# a / the balcony

Tags: articles

> -How did you spend your last summer?
>   -We rented a house in Finland. I went out a lot but my parents spent half of the time on **a/the balcony** sunbathing.

If the house has got 2 balconies, then I use a balcony

If the house has got 1 balcony, then I use the balcony

is that right?

Answer (score 2):

There is an accepted usage of the definite article which occurs especially with prepositional phrases such as 'at the X', 'in the Y', 'on the Z', 'out of the W'... – a usage where it is *not* being claimed that a particular member of the set of all local X's ... is being specified:

> When I was at the butcher's ...
>
> We always enjoy ourselves at the cinema.
>
> He spends too much time at the pub. (There will usually be more than
>   one pub, etc).
>
> He spends too much time in the bathroom / office. (There may well be
>   more than one such room, etc).
>
> He spends too much time on the toilet.
>
> Is there anything on the television that we could watch tonight? (You
>   may have 4)
>
> I hear a lot of things on the street. (becoming more figurative)
>
> I was looking out (of) the window when I saw a hoopoe.

'On the balcony' has probably reached this idiomatic status, whereas 'at the school' say **does** refer to a particular X - the equivalent idiom is 'at school' in this case. There is an article showing different usages (not totally standardised) for 'go to hospital' and 'go to the hospital' [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1485806). Perversely, 'go to infirmary' is very uncommon.

This idiomatic usage is very common where specifying which particular X etc is not considered important. Of course, there are other conflicting usages of the articles (a/an, the; zero), and specification is normal with *the*:

We rented a house in Finland. I went out a lot but my parents spent half of the time on the upstairs / oh-so-tempting / beautiful old ... balcony sunbathing.

Comment: How about the sentence I went to kitchen and grabbed a mug. Is this correct? Or should I say I went to the kitchen and grabbed one of the mugs?

Answer (score 0):

If the house had two balconies, on one of which your parents spent most of their days, I would say 'on either of the two balconies'. Saying 'a balcony' rather suggests a number of different balconies in different buildings were used'.

But if the house only had one balcony, and it was the only one on which they sunbathed, then it would be quite correct to use 'the' and incorrect to use 'a'.

The only problem with using 'either of the balconies', is that you might want to avoid the impression of showing off (because your house had two balconies), in which case I would simply stick with 'the balcony'.